# url rewriting with QUERY_STRING

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite `http://example.com/test/index.php?id=123` 
to `http://example.com/test/item/123/` and `http://example.com/test/index.php?id=123` redirect to the human friendly url.
I don't know what is wrong in my htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /test/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([a-z0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/item/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^item/([a-z0-9]+)/$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following RewriteRule in your `/test/.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

#redirect old url to the new one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /test/index\.php\?id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /test/item/%1? [L,R=301]
#internally map new url to the old one
RewriteRule ^item/(.+)/?$ /test/index.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Nice and precious, thank you — it's work with my regexp `[a-z0-9]+`